# Как внедрить свой js код на все страницы?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как сделать так, чтобы определенный JS код сработал при загрузке любой страницы?
Нужно чтобы работал как ContentScript, с активной страницей, но без клика на расширение (автоматически запускался)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [мана](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) гугла.
Тот же `content_scripts`, только указываешь через `matches` на какие страницы инжектиться будет.
На все страницы можно как-то так:

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*", "https://*"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["js.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Ну у меня сейчас так и работает) Но чтобы скрипт что то менял на странице - нужно нажимать на расширение.
Вопрос в том: можно ли как то сделать, чтобы ContentScript запускался автоматически при загрузке страницы

Comment: @danilatorsu, Хм... У этих скриптов есть доступ к DOM (см. ману), при заходе на страницу, которая совпадает с `matches`, они инжектируются и выполняются. Вроде всё, как Вы хотите...

Comment: @danilatorsu , может быть вам не хватает  [window.onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)?

Comment: оказывается все нормально,я ставил matches "<all_urls>" просто, невнимательно просмотрев документацию

Comment: Кстати теперь запись "matches": ["http://*", "https://*"]," вызывает ошибку

Comment: Нужно ставить "matches": "*://*",

Answer (score 0):

Может подойдет вставка js кода непоредствено в страницу: http://habrahabr.ru/post/147111/ хотя и обычный content_script должен так работать

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше мнение?

Answer (score 0):

Вот как правильно:
Пишете в background.js в фоновой странице:

```
var injection = function() { // Сам скрипт, вводимый в страницу

var pasteScript; // content.js
pasteScript = document.createElement("script");
pasteScript.href = chrome.tabs.getURL("content.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].insertBefore(pasteScript);
};

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { // Инъекция скрипта на страницу
code: "(" + injection.ToString + ")()"
});
```

И не забудьте приписать в manifest.json:

```
"background": {
  "persistent": true,
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "\u003Call_urls>"
     ],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
"web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"] // Вот это надо приписать
```

Работает в автоматическом режиме.